# Find Quarter from first day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to find the Quarter from the firstday of the week.

For example, The first day of the week is `12/31/2012`

I want the quarter to say Q1 2013. But if I find the Qtr from the specific date it says Q4 2012.

Comment: why quarter has to be Q1 2013 for 12/31/2012?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work for all circumstances in your case, so please test out with different dates:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = '2012-12-31'

SELECT 
    qtr = DATEPART(quarter, DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(weekday, @Date), @date)),
    YearNum = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(weekday, @Date), @date))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Oracle - annual week table... May give you some ideas:

```
-- ISO_WK# --
SELECT mydate
  , TRUNC(mydate, 'w') wk_starts
  , TRUNC(mydate, 'w') + 7 - 1/86400 wk_ends
  , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'IW')) ISO_wk#  
FROM
(
 SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-1 + LEVEL AS mydate  -- 1st day of yr-1 day --
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
  (-- First day of curr year – first day of past year --
   SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12), 'YEAR') "Num of Days"   
     FROM dual
  )
 )
/
```